# Do i need license for make free demo based on Futurama world?

Tags: licensing, demo

I want to make demo that shows my skills (for hiring) and chose a theme - Simulate Interactive District of Futurama world. So it will consist 3d models and maybe sounds from Futurama tv series. Also it will be published as video on my blog site and probably Youtube (channel without any monetization).

Do i need any Rights/Agreements for doing this?

Thanks.

Comment: If you want to show your skills, wouldn't it be better if you made an original IP instead?

Comment: @TomTsagk It's not artistic skills, it's programming skills)

Comment: You can still make an original IP, recruiters will focus more on gameplay than the assets themselves, so it wouldn't matter to them if they saw a character from Futurama, or a random character that nobody knows. Plus it would be less headache for you.

Comment: I choose Futurama just for fun, cause its my favourite tv serial. But it's seem that create uniq world\district would be really less headache)
Thx for your reply)

Comment: For your consideration: If you want to show your programming skills, then make it minimalist, and make it evident that the assets are placeholders. If not simple shapes, stuff from public domain or permissive licenses. Do not let anything in the art distract from the code. In fact, do not let the potential employers mistake you for a bad artists when you are a good programmer. Furthermore, find ways to make programming more visible, such as rendering influence maps, the current state of state machines and behavior trees, planned paths, view cones, last seen location of the player, etc.

Comment: Hello @Theraot ! Its really great advise, many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you distribute creative works you did not create yourself to an audience, you need to have copyright on those works. It does not matter if you have commercial interest or not.

So if you use the intellectual property of 20th Century Fox without their permission, they can sue you.

<sub>(but do not rely on legal advise of anonymous strangers on the Internet like me)</sub>

But regardless of the legal situation, you have to consider what impression a portfolio like that makes on people you apply to. When they see "oh, I have seen that asset on Futurama", then they will wonder how much more of your portfolio are 3rd party resources you didn't create yourself. A portfolio is supposed to show off what *you* can do, not what work from other people you like. That means your portfolio should consist mainly of things *you* created. Preferably *only* things you created, but if you use any 3rd party resources in your portfolio, make very clear what you have taken from elsewhere and what you created yourself.

Comment: I want to use as much 3rd party resource (models) as possible, it's about programming skills, not artistic. BTW, thx for answer. It's seems that better to create uniq world... – justix 12 mins ago   Delete